# Strange ActiveRecord model behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

I have model

```
class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :telephone
  validates_uniqueness_of :telephone
  validates_telephone_number_of :telephone
  before_validation :telephone_normalize
end
```

in rails console

```
a = Owner.new(:telephone => '949123456')
=> #<Owner id: nil, telephone: "949123456", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
1.9.3-p362 :002 > a.valid?
Owner Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "owners" WHERE "owners"."telephone" = '+421949123456' LIMIT 1
=> false
1.9.3-p362 :003 > a
=> #<Owner id: nil, telephone: "421949123456", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

The same, when I save unique number:

```
1.9.3-p362 :006 > a.telephone = '949123457'
=> "949123457" 
1.9.3-p362 :007 > a.save
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
Owner Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "owners" WHERE "owners"."telephone" = '+421949123457' LIMIT 1
SQL (2.3ms)  INSERT INTO "owners" ("created_at", "telephone", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Wed, 16 Jan 2013 11:55:44 UTC +00:00], ["telephone", "421949123457"], ["updated_at", Wed, 16 Jan 2013 11:55:44 UTC +00:00]]
(88.3ms)  commit transaction
=> true
```

Rails (3.2.11) omits '+' in the beginning of number. Type of number is string. It also saves it without plus sign (if it is unique), but when validating, it calls with plus sign.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunetaly there was bug in my `validates_telephone_number_of` validator. It had modified attribute :-/

Say

```
> a = 'aaa' # => 'aaa'
> b = a.to_s # => 'aaa'
> b << 'c' # => 'aaac'
> b  # => 'aaac'
> a  # => 'aaac'
```

It is needed to use `b = a.to_s.dup`.

Answer (score 1):

It think **telephone** column in database is **integer** type. So the string you have passed is out of its range. That's why you have face this problem.